# Is npm install affecting Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, npm-install, laravel-5.7

I am working on the Laravel project, and intend to use Vue.js as its client-side scripting. When I searched the internet, I found that I had to use the `npm install` command. My question is if I run the order, will it affect the project I'm working on?

For example, in the directory structure or variable section?

Answer (score 1):

It will change only `package.json` and `/node_modules` folder (it will download vue.js last version package into this folder) in your root directory. But it won't affect your existing codebase until you don't use them via importing or accessing it. It is like installing a package with `composer`, but not using it. The downloaded package will stay in `/vendor` folder and package name in `composer.json`, `composer.lock`